# ValueError: Unsupported data type 13 in tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow-lite

So, I recently converted my custom object detection model from Tensorflow '1.15.0' to Tensorflow lite so I can implement it on a raspberry PI 3
But, when I tryed to test it using a camera and opencv '4.5.1' I got this error 'Unsupported data type 13 in tensor'.
Can anyone help me understand this error?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the latest TensorFlow Lite runtime version, for example, TensorFlow 2.5 or beyonds in the Raspberry Pi.

The data type 13 is TFLite resource type, which is supported from the TensorFlow 2.5 version.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
Actually, I am using the latest TF Lite runtime version 2.5. Yet I am still getting this error.