# ValueError: Unsupported data type 14 in tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

**System information**

- Have I written custom code : `interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="models/saved_model.tflite")`
- OS Platform and Distribution : **`RaspberryPi 3B+`**
- TensorFlow Git version : `v2.4.0-0-g582c8d2`
- TensorFlow version : `2.4.0`
- Installation Source : [`https://github.com/bitsy-ai/tensorflow-arm-bin/releases/download/v2.4.0/tensorflow-2.4.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl`](https://github.com/bitsy-ai/tensorflow-arm-bin/releases/download/v2.4.0/tensorflow-2.4.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl)
- Python version: `Python 3.7.3`
- More Info about the **tflite** Model : Custom trained **EfficientDet-B0** on `40` classes

##### ERROR :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect.py", line 8, in <module>
    interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="models/saved_model.tflite")
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/lite/python/interpreter.py", line 209, in __init__
    model_path, self._custom_op_registerers))
ValueError: Unsupported data type 14 in tensor
Unsupported data type 14 in tensor
Unsupported data type 14 in tensor
Unsupported data type 14 in tensor
Unsupported data type 14 in tensor
Unsupported data type 14 in tensor
```

> Note : If you are suggesting me to upgrade or downgrade the packages, please provide necessary code with it.

Thanks !!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67106790/valueerror-unsupported-data-type-13-in-tensor

Answer (score 1):

Kindly upgrade your TFLite version. Your model is using TFLite Resource type which doesn't exist in your TFLite runtime library.